how to evaluate the explicit formula for the quotient powers of the Dedekind eta function
I'm working on a thesis in number theory, specifically focusing on modular forms, particularly the Dedekind eta functions. I want to know if there is a way to obtain the explicit expression for the quotients of eta functions of the form
$$\frac{\eta(l\tau)^n}{\eta(\tau)}$$ For $l$ and $n$ integers, their reply will be of great help.
